# Why I can not find balanceWhite in opencv 3.0 beta?

Tags: c++, opencv

I download and installed prebuild OpenCV 3.0 beta (C++) and tried to play with some of its functions. But I could not find a way to use balanceWhite which is documented here:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/xphoto/doc/whitebalance.html#balancewhite

How can I use this function?

It is not defined and I can not find any definition for it and no header file to include.

Comment: When you say you could not find a way to use it, do you mean you're not clear on what the arguments to the function do? Or can you not actually call it because it doesn't link or something?

Comment: What platform are you doing this on? If you're on linux, you can look through your `/usr/include` directory for something that resembles the opencv header files. Also, to the best of my knowledge, openCV also uses the `cv` namespace, so perhaps you could try `cv::balanceWhite(...)` as well?

Comment: @MSalmo Thanks. I am using Visual studio on windows and I already used cv::balancedWhite and also cv::xphoto::balancedWhite without any success. I also searched the include files and could not find them there.

Answer (score 1):

to use the xphoto module, you will need to download and build the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/) repo

Answer (score 0):

Since the modules are not yet definitive, they haven't been added to the library yet.

However, you can find them [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/xphoto)